# Problem with a prepared statement

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I have this code:

```
 Date start = new Date(Integer.parseInt(jTextField4.getText()), Integer.parseInt(jTextField16.getText()), Integer.parseInt(jTextField17.getText()));  
        Date end = new Date(Integer.parseInt(jTextField5.getText()), Integer.parseInt(jTextField18.getText()), Integer.parseInt(jTextField19.getText()));
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        preparedStatement1 = connection.prepareStatement("insert into sportmangg(customer_code,"
             + "sportman_code, start, finish, salary,amount,box salary,private salary, food salary, "
             + "other salary, bime salary, number) "
             + "values (? ,?, ? , ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?");
      preparedStatement1.setString(1,jTextField15.getText());
     preparedStatement1.setString(2, jTextField1.getText());
     preparedStatement1.setDate(3, start);
     preparedStatement1.setDate(4, end);
     preparedStatement1.setInt(5, Integer.parseInt(jTextField6.getText()) );
     preparedStatement1.setInt(6,Integer.parseInt(jTextField14.getText()) );
     preparedStatement1.setInt(7, Integer.parseInt(jTextField7.getText()));
     preparedStatement1.setInt(8, Integer.parseInt(jTextField8.getText()));
     preparedStatement1.setInt(9, Integer.parseInt(jTextField9.getText()));
     preparedStatement1.setInt(10, Integer.parseInt(jTextField11.getText()));
     preparedStatement1.setInt(11, Integer.parseInt(jTextField10.getText()));
     preparedStatement1.setInt(12, Integer.parseInt(jTextField20.getText()));
     preparedStatement1.executeUpdate();
```

but it has this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'salary,private salary, food salary, other salary, bime salary, number) values ('' at line 1
```

What is the problem?

Comment: @diEcho, this is java not javascript

Comment: you added a bounty, but would you please address why the two answers you have don't apply?

Comment: i press it **wrong**.what can i do until cancel it?

Comment: You cannot cancel a bounty. If your question was answered, you should accept the answer that was best.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You really shouldn't have spaces in the field name. Try surrounding it with ``

Comment: or just replace the spaces with underscore _ and forget the `

Answer (score 3):

Column names with spaces in them are a ***very*** bad idea.

If you must have them, surround them with backticks:

```
`private salary`
```

Comment: Okay, I've edited it.  I've never found a way in StackOverflow's markdown syntax to put literal backticks inside inline code formatting, so I had to create a new line indented as for block code.

Answer (score 1):

You missed `)` in the last line of your SQL query so it should be:

```
+ "  values (? ,?, ? , ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?   )";
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this: 
https://github.com/stuparmihailo/util4j/releases/tag/v1.0 
It's some simple project and has nice way for creating statements:
`String query = "INSERT INTO table VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
StatementUtil.fill(stmt, 45, "text", 2, null, new Date(), false, 3.5);`

Answer (score 0):

You should replace private salary with private_salary and keep working with acceptable column name conventions.

Answer (score 0):

column or table names should not have spaces. Join them by underscore. and make them upper case... these are not rules but accepted ways of working with DB objects. If names cannot be changed in the DB and you are stuck with something like some  salary, then `some salary` should help.

Answer (score 0):

mehdi; 
I think what you have to do is all of this:

1. change names of
   space-named columns (private salary,
   food salary, other salary, bime
   salary) either by replacing spaces by underscores
   (recommended by naming conventions) or by
   surrounding names with grave accent char:

   > `box salary`, `private salary`, `food salary`, `other salary`, `bime
   >   salary`
2. Fix this line adding final parentheses

   > + "values (? ,?, ? , ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?");

   it must say:

   > + "values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?**);**");
3. Finally I'd recommend to take out prepareStatement argument to a String or StringBuffer variable, say "sqlString" or something, so you can manipulate it more transparently. Something like this:

> ```
> String sqlString = "";
> sqlString += " insert into sportmangg";
> sqlString += " (customer_code, sportman_code, start, finish,";
> sqlString += " salary, amount, box_salary, private_salary,";
> sqlString += " food_salary, other_salary, bime_salary, number)";
> sqlString += " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
> preparedStatement1 = connection.prepareStatement(sqlString);
> ```

(or if you use **StringBuffer** use **append** method)